# Angular how to write unit test for callback function in promise

Tags: angular, unit-testing, promise, jasmine

I have a component with a method that is responsible for closing dialog. Dialog close method returns promise.

```
closeDialogAction(callback: Function) {
    this.confirmationDialog.close(true).then(() => {
        callback();
    });
}
```

How to write a unit test that will check I callback was called?
I was trying like this but without success.

```
it('should call callback function after close dialog', () => {
    const cb = jasmine.createSpy('cb');
    this.componentInstance.closeDialogAction(cb);
    expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: could you clarify what is this.confirmationDialog? if it is mocked in the test, then please also provide the object that is used as a mock

Comment: is this something worth unit testing? your test now has deep knowledge about the code and frankly just because you called a method called close, that doesn't mean anything has actually closed.

Comment: Everything is worth testing. confirmationDialog is actually confirming Dialog and close is a method to close that dialog it returns promise because there is closing animation. I'm passing a callback function for different action after closing animation is finished. So I think it is quite important to have unit test for that call.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't already do that, you need to mock the `close()` function of the confirmationDialog so it just returns a resolved `Promise` instantly.

Since you're dealing with asynchronous code, you have to wrap the assertion function of `it` in a `fakeAsync` call. This wraps your assertion code in a special testing zone that imitates asynchronous behaviour for you (for more info, see [the fakeAsync documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-fakeasync)). Then you only need to call the `tick` to "advance the (virtual) clock". This ensures that all asynchronous activity will be finished after this call.

This is roughly how your code should look like:

```
it("should call callback", fakeAsync(() => {
    //todo: confirmationDialog should be injected by you via TestBed.get() or something similar
    spyOn(confirmationDialog, "close").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
    const spy = jasmine.createSpy();

    closeDialogAction(spy);

    tick();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Note that the confirmationDialog variable needs to be instantiated by you, either by injecting or by manually creating it, depending on your codebase.